# Will the id of requestAnimationFrame overflow in javascript?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

In javascript, when I call setTimeout, setInterval or requestAnimationFrame, it will return an id which later can be used to cancel it.

But the id is continuously increamenting, especially when called frequently like "requestAnimationFrame". So I am wondering if the id will later be lager enough that will eventually overflowed?

Comment: yes but that would be a long time.

Comment: At 100 frames per second, it will take around 3 million years for the id to overflow a JavaScript Number.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm somewhat unfounded...@Raymond